How to create an enumerate environment with Case 1, Case 2,
How to create an enumerate environment with Case 1, Case 2,...instead of the bullets?
Thanks.

You should always include a small test document in your questions. This will avoid you getting into problems because users suggest incompatible packages.

Just for example you can use this:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe} %%%% <------optional to show margins
\usepackage{geometry} %%%% <------optional to have the right margins
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}
\newlist{encase}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[encase]{label=Case \arabic*:, leftmargin=2cm}

\begin{document}
Here there is a list:
\begin{encase}
    \item $ab^2-bc$:
    \item $f_x(x,y)=0$:
    \item $\nabla f=0$.
\end{encase}

\end{document}

You can deleted : from \setlist[encase]{label=Case \arabic*:......}.


Thank you so much. Your code works but it is going a bit too much to the left. How can we bring it a bit more inside?

@hochoi Adding leftmargin=2cm for example.

I works perfectly now. Thanks @Sebastiano.

@hochoi I am happy to help you. :-)

Given that your follow-up question showed that you use beamer, you shouldn't use the enumitem package. Instead use mini-templates:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\mode<presentation> { \usetheme{boxes} }


%used to customize the size of the frametitle
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.0ex,dp=0.6ex]{frametitle}
        \hspace*{1ex}\insertframetitle%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\begin{document}    

\begin{frame}
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{1.35cm}
    
    normal text
    \begin{enumerate}[{Case~}1:]
        \item    abc
        \item    abc
    \end{enumerate}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}


